# How to benchmark parallel code?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo

I have some code that I paralellized using `Rayon` hoping to improve its performance, but the results, measured by the `Bencher`, were... most unimpressive. I suspected that it might be caused by the way I am performing the benchmarks (maybe *they* are run in parallel?), so I tested a simpler case.

Consider the following parallelized code, based on the [`quick_sort` crate](https://crates.io/crates/quick_sort):

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate rayon;
extern crate test;

use test::Bencher;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

pub fn sort<T>(arr: &mut [T])
    where T: Send + std::cmp::PartialEq + Ord
{
    qsort(arr, find_pivot, &|a, b| a.cmp(b))
}

pub fn sort_by<T, F>(arr: &mut [T], compare: &F)
    where T: Send + std::cmp::PartialOrd,
          F: Sync + Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering
{
    qsort(arr, find_pivot, compare);
}

fn qsort<T, F>(arr: &mut [T], pivot: fn(&[T], &F) -> usize, compare: &F)
    where T: Send + std::cmp::PartialOrd,
          F: Sync + Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering
{
    let len = arr.len();
    if len <= 1 {
        return;
    }

    let p = pivot(arr, compare);
    let p = partition(arr, p, compare);
    let (l, r) = arr.split_at_mut(p + 1);
    if p > len / 2 {
        rayon::join(
            || qsort(r, pivot, compare),
            || qsort(l, pivot, compare)
        );
    } else {
        rayon::join(
            || qsort(l, pivot, compare),
            || qsort(r, pivot, compare)
        );
    }
}

fn find_pivot<T, F>(arr: &[T], compare: &F) -> usize
    where T: Send + std::cmp::PartialOrd,
          F: Sync + Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering
{
    let (l, r) = (0, arr.len() - 1);
    let m = l + ((r - 1) / 2);
    let (left, middle, right) = (&arr[l], &arr[m], &arr[r]);
    if (compare(middle, left) != Ordering::Less) && (compare(middle, right) != Ordering::Greater) {
        m
    } else if (compare(left, middle) != Ordering::Less) &&
              (compare(left, right) != Ordering::Greater) {
        l
    } else {
        r
    }
}


fn partition<T, F>(arr: &mut [T], p: usize, compare: &F) -> usize
    where T: std::cmp::PartialOrd,
          F: Sync + Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering
{
    if arr.len() <= 1 {
        return p;
    }

    let last = arr.len() - 1;
    let mut next_pivot = 0;
    arr.swap(last, p);
    for i in 0..last {
        if compare(&arr[i], &arr[last]) == Ordering::Less {
            arr.swap(i, next_pivot);
            next_pivot += 1;
        }
    }

    arr.swap(next_pivot, last);
    next_pivot
}

#[bench]
fn bench_qsort(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut vec = vec![ 3, 97, 50, 56, 58, 80, 91, 71, 83, 65,
                       92, 35, 11, 26, 69, 44, 42, 75, 40, 43,
                       63,  5, 62, 56, 35,  3, 51, 97, 100, 73,
                       42, 41, 79, 86, 93, 58, 65, 96, 66, 36,
                       17, 97,  6, 16, 52, 30, 38, 14, 39,  7,
                       48, 83, 37, 97, 21, 58, 41, 59, 97, 37,
                       97,  9, 24, 78, 77,  7, 78, 80, 11, 79,
                       42, 30, 39, 27, 71, 61, 12,  8, 49, 62,
                       69, 48,  8, 56, 89, 27,  1, 80, 31, 62,
                        7, 15, 30, 90, 75, 78, 22, 99, 97, 89];

    b.iter(|| { sort(&mut vec); } );
}
```

Results of `cargo bench`:

```
running 1 test
test bench_qsort ... bench:      10,374 ns/iter (+/- 296) // WHAT
```

While the results for the sequential code (`extern crate quick_sort`) are:

```
running 1 test
test bench_qsort ... bench:       1,070 ns/iter (+/- 65)
```

I also tried benchmarking with longer vectors, but the results were consistent. In addition, I performed some tests using GNU time and it looks like the parallel code is faster with bigger vectors, as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Can I use `Bencher` to benchmark parallel code?

Answer (score 0):

The array you use in the test is so small that the parallel code really *is* slower in that case.

There's some overhead to launching tasks in parallel, and the memory access will be slower when different threads access memory on the same cache line.

For iterators to avoid overhead on tiny arrays there's [`with_min_len`](https://docs.rs/rayon/0.9.0/rayon/iter/trait.IndexedParallelIterator.html#method.with_min_len), but for `join` you probably need to implement parallel/non-parallel decision yourself.

---

With 100 times larger array:

```
with rayon:            3,468,891 ns/iter (+/- 95,859)
without rayon:         4,227,220 ns/iter (+/- 635,260)
rayon if len > 1000:   3,166,570 ns/iter (+/- 66,329)
```

The relatively small speed-up is expected for this task, because it's memory-bound (there's no complex computation to parallelize).

Comment: OP states: *I also tried benchmarking with longer vectors, but the results were consistent* — can you provide more detail or facts about why you think that the OP is incorrect?